# Android - What is the best way to send a JSON to a remote server and wait for an asynchronous response

Tags: android, json, request, response

I want to send a JSON object to a remote server from my android mobile client. I'm a bit confused from the examples I found, Some uses Sockets the other HttpClient.

Is There a way to define a callback method?

What would be best practice in order to get an asynchronous response?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check out the below link  :

http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

There you will detailed explanation for sending and receiving the data from server. By taking reference I have write Program to send to the server and receiving from the server.

Comment: Thanks,
Same results I got from googeling the subject, however I can't spot the place where I can specify a callback and have it asynchronous

Comment: If it's help you then accept the answer and  vote up the answer.